# Oracle SQL Get previous month from 6 digit number NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle

The month field is YYYYMM in the form of a NUMBER.
I want to get the previous month. I already calculate the previous month to December if the current month is January Eg: 201301 gets converted to 201212. (I use MOD to check last if last two digits get evaluated to 1, if yes, it decrements year and appends 12 as the month)

I'm trying to get the previous month if the current month is any month other than January. For this I tried-

```
  1) select  CONCAT( SUBSTR(201405,1,4),  MOD(201405,100) - 1 )  from dual;
  2) select  CONCAT( SUBSTR(201405,1,4),  SUBSTR(201405,5,6) - 1 )  from dual;
```

In both the cases it returns 20144, i.e it drops the 0 from the current month. So for the value of 201405, the it should return 201404.

Comment: Can you use `TO_DATE()`, do the operation, and then convert back into a number?  That would cover even the January -> December case along with all the others.

Comment: You should store dates as dates rather than numbers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(DAT,'YYYYMM'),-1),'YYYYMM')) PREV_MONTH 
FROM 
(SELECT 201405 DAT FROM DUAL);
```

Output:

```
PREV_MONTH
----------
    201404
1 row selected.
```

Comment: This could be more complicated, because there is no function like add_weeks, and you need to have many things in consideration. If you have this dimension, then you can order by this field, and get the previous value. For this you can use lag or lead analytic function in dependency of order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INTERVAL` (of course the whole thing won't be ANSI-compliant, so it might be silly to introduce ANSI intervals, but still):

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(201405), 'YYYYMM') - INTERVAL '1' MONTH, 'YYYYMM'))
  FROM dual;
```

You can actually omit the inner call to `TO_CHAR()` and just let Oracle do the implicit conversion (not sure I approve of that, though):

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(201405, 'YYYYMM') - INTERVAL '1' MONTH, 'YYYYMM'))
  FROM dual;
```

Or you could try this:

```
WITH d1 AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(201405), 'YYYYMM') - INTERVAL '1' MONTH AS new_date
      FROM dual
)
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM new_date) * 100 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM new_date)
  FROM d1;
```